# Installing ODBC Driver on Heroku

Tags: python, heroku, pyodbc

I'm trying to use `pyodbc` to connect to my MSSQL database hosted on azure, and while it works locally, I cannot get it to work when I push the changes to Heroku. I'm running Windows. This is the error it gives me:

> pyodbc.Error: ('01000', "[01000] [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Can't open
>   lib 'ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server' : file not found (0)
>   (SQLDriverConnect)")

This is how I start the connection:

```
cnxn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server};
       SERVER=serverurl;
       DATABASE=db;
       UID=user;
       PWD=password')
```

This is my Aptfile where I included a download link to the driver for Heroku:

```
unixodbc
unixodbc-dev
python-pyodbc
libsqliteodbc
https://packages.microsoft.com/ubuntu/16.04/prod/pool/main/m/msodbcsql/msodbcsql_13.1.9.2-1_amd64.deb
```

And my `requirements.txt`:

```
...
pyodbc==4.0.24
```

I even have a buildpack installed (https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-apt). From what I understand, the driver isn't present on Heroku's end, and as such it can't locate it.

If this really is the case, how can I get Heroku to download the driver? I've tried placing the download link in the Aptfile as seen above, but it doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this can be solved with the same methodology as a similar question [Python cant find ODBC Driver on Heroku after setting everything](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59306332/python-cant-find-odbc-driver-on-heroku-after-setting-everything).

**tldr**: the solution was to precompile ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server on an Ubuntu 18.04 environment and copy the required driver files over to Heroku via this buildpack `https://github.com/matt-bertoncello/python-pyodbc-buildpack.git`. The same process sbould be able to work by precompiling a ODBC Driver 13 on an Ubuntu 16.04 environment.

Comment: How do we install Driver 13 on Heroku? Driver 17 seems to be incompatible